# Landscape mode is wrong in iOS 8 - Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've tried the following code to my landscpae ipad application and it works fine ...but know in xcode6 it appears wrong (see the print screen)

```
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.loginRegisterView;
    CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57079633);
    [self.window setTransform:rotate];

    CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    self.window.bounds = contentRect;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and when I launch the app appears: https://imageshack.com/i/kqo1EBgAp

EDIT:

Now, I don't rotate the window manually...only in General Tab, like the print screen

https://imageshack.com/i/idzqoTZQp

And here is the xib file

https://imageshack.com/i/ipB1cOpGp

and here how it appears on device

https://imageshack.com/i/eyioC4PCp

Comment: Do you want your app to be only landscape? If so, the easiest thing might be to select the landscape orientations only in the target configuration panel (General tab) instead of manually rotating it.

Comment: I did this..the problem is that the app appears in landscape mode but the view is like the print screen

Comment: Try not running it in the resizable iPad simulator, select an actual device (iPad 2, iPad Air, etc) Also try running it on an actual device.

Comment: If you already have the app set to landscape mode, remove the rotation transform lines and it should automatically go to landscape.  In addition, you should use AutoLayout to make sure that it sizes the view itself appropriately for landscape.

Comment: Hey, Ladessa, did you get answer? I am also facing same kind of issue after manually rotation from portrait to landscape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following code in viewDidLoad

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    [self.view setTransform:rotate];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
    [super viewDidLoad];
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

EDIT:

If add in

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions it works for all the views


    CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    [self.window setTransform:rotate];
    [self.window setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue seems to be the order of calls when you set up the window in your app delegate.  You need to call `makeKeyAndVisible` before you assign the `rootViewController`.  The following works:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
self.window.rootViewController = self.myMainViewController;
```

But if you change the order to:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
self.window.rootViewController = self.myMainViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

You get the behavior you are experiencing.